# How load two value via one parameter in function

Tags: javascript

is it possible to read two different values over one parameter in a function? I need to load two values in one parameter into a function.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You could use javascript object for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Simplest example:

```js
function test(params) {
    return params.first + params.second;
}

console.log(test({
    first: 3,
    second: 4
}));
```

If you care about the names, then:

```js
function test(params) {
    var {first, second} = params;
    return first +  second;
}

console.log(test({
    first: 3,
    second: 4
}));
```